# Sorting/Alphabetizing C++ methods in Eclipse (not in outline, in the code)

Tags: c++, eclipse, sorting, methods

So i know there is the way to sort the methods in the outline view and after doing a search online i see there is a way to sort the methods in the code for java. Is there a similar thing for .cpp files? I want to sort all the methods over many .cpp and .h files.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: OMG! That's horrendous! If you worked on my team, we'd tar'n'feather you then run you out of town, or even possibly string you up on a bad day :-) You should probably be keeping your code organised functionally rather than alphabetically, and just use the outline view if you need to find things alphabetically. Just my two cents worth, and you'll probably consider even _that_ overpriced.

Comment: Not my code, not my choice. That's the way "they" want it so i want to find a way where i don't have to do it by hand.

Comment: That's pretty awful, lol.  Why not just write a simple program that will tokenize all of your methods, sort them, then write them to another file?

Comment: Oh, and why do so many people start their questions with "So"?

Comment: Because i was really really REALLY hoping there was a way that i could just right click -> sort in eclipse to make this very quick and painless :) I figured you can do it with java, so someone must have done it in c too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do this in Eclipse. I am going to switch to Visual Studio as i see there are many plugins for this idea.

Answer (score 0):

I actually saw this in the Java Code Style plugin the other day. It will alphabetize your properties and methods. I'd never use it, but i guess it's there for a reason. This would be the place to look if there is an equivalent for CDT:

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_c_code_style_pref.htm

Comment: Ya, i saw that too. The thing is i can only find it for the Java side. There is no setting like that for the c++. Under Java preferences there is a appearance -> Member Sort order. But for c++ there is only an appearance tab with no sorting options. I have looked thoroughly on the page before and no luck :(